# Wordpress - get_the_category - Массив данных последнего материала

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно, что кто-либо сталкивался со следующей ситуацией.

На сайте используется запрос вида (код установлен в sidebar, тестируется ситуация на страницах категории записей - шаблон archive):

```
$categories = get_the_category();
```

Краткое пояснение, что далее используется код для вывода ссылки и наименования родительской категории в sidebar.

Собственно, "проблема" в следующем - в массиве (get_the_category()) выводятся данные от последней добавленной записи в категории, но не от самой категории.

Сам цикл вывода информации в записях (на странице архива), имеет вид:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
...
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Что может быть причиной тому, что данные в sidebar выводятся не конкретно просматриваемой категории (выводятся данные последнего добавленного поста)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так функция работает по определению.

**get_the_category()**

Получает массив данных о категориях относящихся к указанному посту.

Функцию можно использовать за пределами Цикла WordPress, если указать ID поста.

https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_category

Comment: Спасибо за "направление", вопрос удалось решить.